# IsolatedStorage persistence across multiple tabs

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, isolatedstorage

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(appSettings.Contains("test"))
        {
           appSettings["test"] = textBox1.Text;

        }
        else
        {
            appSettings.Add("test", textBox1.Text);

        }
        appSettings.Save();

    }

    private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (appSettings.Contains("test"))
        {
            textBlock1.Text = (string)appSettings["test"];
        }
        else
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "Storage is empty";
        }
    }

}
```

Then I open the application in two separate tabs of the same browser.From one tab I save some text into isolatedstorage.From the second tab I try to retrieve the value.But I am not able to retrieve the latest value i saved in isolatedstorage.Most often,I have to refresh the tab 2-3 times to get the latest value.Isn't it supposed to be updated realtime since I am calling Save() after adding value to isolatedstorage object.

Please let me know what is wrong with this code snippet?Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation mentions unexpected behavior if you have multiple out-of-browser instances running on the same computer.  I know you said you're running both in the same browser, but I wonder if you might have better luck using IsolatedStorageFile instead.